# Magento 2 How to get disable/enable child categories?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, category, category-tree, sub-categories

I am working with display all categories on a custom page, either it is enabled or disabled.

When I try to get child categories with "**getChildrenCategories()**", but it is **returning only enabled child categories it is not returning the disabled child categories**. I need both types of child categories.

**How can I get the all child categories which are disabled/enabled?**

please check the code as below.

```
protected $_categoryFactory;
public function __construct(
\Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
){
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
}

public function getAllChildCategories($categoryId)
{
    $categoryObj = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    if($categoryObj->hasChildren()) {
        return $categoryObj->getChildrenCategories();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code.

```
public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver, 
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory  $categoryFactory,
        array $data = array()) 
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $registry, $categoryHelper,$data);
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
     }

    public function getCategoryList()
    {
      $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
      $collection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
              ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
              ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren());
      return $collection;

    }
```

I hope its work for you.

Comment: I need enabled and disabled both categories. this will only get enabled/active category.

Comment: please check with it, i update collection, try with remove filter is_Active, hope its work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Default children categories only return as active. You need to that function changes to get the categories that you want to override.

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category.php
```

> From

```
public function getChildrenCategories($category)
{
    $collection = $category->getCollection();
    /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection */
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect(
        'url_key'
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'name'
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'all_children'
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'is_anchor'
    )->addAttributeToFilter(
        'is_active',
        1
    )->addIdFilter(
        $category->getChildren()
    )->setOrder(
        'position',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_ASC
    )->joinUrlRewrite();

    return $collection;
}
```

> To

```
public function getChildrenCategories($category)
{
    $collection = $category->getCollection();
    /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection */
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect(
        'url_key'
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'name'
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'all_children'
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'is_anchor'
    )->addIdFilter(
        $category->getChildren()
    )->setOrder(
        'position',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_ASC
    )->joinUrlRewrite();

    return $collection;
}
```

From the above functions remove "is_active" filter too that function